# Dimming 'visited posts' in flag dashboard does not work for election nominations

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, election, flag-dashboard

The flag dashboard for moderators slightly dims entries for questions which you have visited (presuming you don't want to take any action now, so you can focus on other flags).

This feature does not work for elections, if a comment under one of the nominations is flagged. Visiting the election page has no effect on the flag dashboard.

Comment: I feel like a lot of mod pages on the site just don't know how to handle election nominations. On many pages, such as comment dashboards, lists of posts by a deleted user, etc., links to questions and answers show the title of the question, but election nomination posts just don't appear at all (seemingly because the site doesn't know what text to display there instead).

Comment: Could be, yes. I'm not actively hunting those bugs, just reporting them when I encounter something odd :)